# Can I use jQuery UI 1.12.1 with jQuery 3.x?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I changed my jQuery `1.7.2` to `3.1.1` and changed my jQuery UI from version `1.8.16` to version `1.12.1`.

Quite a few of my existing JS stuff broke, like styling of buttons, and `dialog` behaves in unexpected manner, i.e. half of modal dialog is covered up by the mysterious `<div class="ui-widget-overlay ui-front"></div>`

I suspected jQuery UI to be at fault due to the covering above.  I went to jQuery UI site and I see that stable version is for `jQuery 1.7+`.

Does that mean that I should be using jQuery 1.x with jQuery UI, or can I use jQuery 3.x okay (plus ... try to figure out why my styling and functionality broke)?

Comment: Did you change both jquery-ui css AND js files? Did you refresh (&clear cache)?

Comment: Did you update the code to take into account all the breaking changes between 1.8.16->1.12.1 and all the changes between 1.7.2 and 3.1.1?

Comment: @Dekel, Was not aware of jquery-ui CSS... will take a look.    Kevin: no, did not take anything into account.

Comment: @Dekel - downloading and updating CSS fixed the issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

jQueryUI supports the following jQuery version range:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">=1.7.0 <4.0.0"
},
```

I'd say you're good to go.

Source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/package.json#L49

It might be that you're seeing a lot of broken components because either you're not importing their CSS or you're overriding their CSS.

Comment: It may work, but not fully. Consider to use [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate) to have polyfills for deprecated functions.

Comment: Most of animations do not work UI 1.12.1 and jQuery 3.4.1. For example jqueryUI hide(easingname, options, callback) method will complete the animation then show the object again.

Answer (score 12):

Can you use jQuery-UI with jQuery 3.2.1 ?

Imho you can not without having serious problems.
See the given example below.

Assume the following configuration:

- jQuery 3.2.1 (CDN)
- jQuery UI 1.12.1 (CDN)
- Detection jQ Migrate 3.0.0 for error detection.

I get the following errors:

- jQuery.expr[":"] is now jQuery.expr.pseudos in jquery-ui.min.js
- jQuery.expr.filters is now jQuery.expr.pseudos in query-ui.min.js
- jQuery.unique is deprecated, use jQuery.uniqueSort

Comment: These are warnings rather than errors and it does all appear to work as expected. It's odd that jQuery UI doesn't use the latest jQuery syntax though.

Comment: I believe they're only warnings due to the use of jQ Migrate. Without that, I'm pretty sure that they'd be full-on errors.

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles across this question: as of jquery 3.4.1, all of the deprecated stuff that jquery-ui uses will throw warnings in the jqmigrate plugin, but they WILL still work - they are not full on errors. The aliases still exist.

The jquery-ui authors appear to not really care about updating their library to use the non-deprecated aliases either, so unless you want to fork jquery-ui you sort of have to live with it.

Comment: Because the jQuery UI library isn't updated yet, I created a patch. See here: https://github.com/DenisLabrecque/jQuery-UI-Fixed-for-3.5.1

Comment: Thanks Denis - that is very useful!